# Existence of an element using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have seen a couple of ways to test if an element exists. One way:

```
private boolean existsElement(String id) {
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.id(id));
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And another way:

```
Boolean isPresent = driver.findElements(By.yourLocator).size() > 0
```

but adding an exception to test something isn't good practice and using the size method will take too long if you have an implicit wait.

Are there any other efficient ways to test for existence? If not, which of the two will be the preferred way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`findElement(By)`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) documentation:

> findElement should not be used to look for non-present elements, use [`findElements(By)`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-) and assert zero length response instead.

Comment: Hm, what do they mean by "assert zero length response"?

Comment: This is exactly the second option you provided

Comment: Oh, I see so the second option will be the preferred choice. Thanks!

Comment: It definitely is as it does not use ``Exception`` to control the flow of execution.

Comment: Last question. Since this is a broad usage, will it be a good idea to create a method that checks for existence and place it in a utilities folder class or should I place the method in a page object class?

Comment: I would probably create a util method but this a matter of personal preference.

Comment: That was my thought too. Thank you!